# Sql Query to fetch a matching rows for two criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I have the fields called language and the values are like `hindi,english`.

So if I select `hindi` and `english`, I used like clause so this rows comes in the result.

But if I use:

```
SELECT * FROM  `rr` WHERE rr LIKE  '%english,hindi%' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This row won't come in the result.

So can any one please help me to solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you store a single language in the language field, or all languages separated by comma?

Comment: all the languages in a single field separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

`BOOLEAN MODE` may help you

```
SELECT * FROM rr WHERE MATCH (rr) 
     AGAINST ('+english +hindi' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Usage :

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE MATCH (col1, col2) AGAINST ('string to be searched')
```

Basing it off of the example here

> MySQL can perform boolean full-text searches using the IN BOOLEAN MODE
>   modifier. With this modifier, certain characters have special meaning
>   at the beginning or end of words in the search string. In the
>   following query, the + and - operators indicate that a word is
>   required to be present or absent, respectively, for a match to occur.
>   Thus, the query retrieves all the rows that contain the word “val1”
>   but that do not contain the word “val2”:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MATCH (COL1,COL2)
    -> AGAINST ('+val1 -val2' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: I have a comma separated languages in a single field. SELECT * FROM rr WHERE MATCH (rr) AGAINST ('english,hindi') but no use. getting some error.